# Solving for $m + n$ given another equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Getting to the question right away:

If two positive integers $m$ and $n$, both bigger than 1, satisfy the equation $1177^2 + m^2 = 1176^2 + n^2$, find the value of $m + n$

For people who are advanced in these type of question, this should feel like a piece of cake, but to me, it's kind of a foxhole. 
I followed standard algebra stuff, and simplified it a bit:
$$1177^2 + m^2 = 1176^2 + n^2$$
$$2353 + m^2 =n^2$$
I can write this another way:
$$m^2 = n^2 - 2353$$

Taking the square root I can get: $$m = \sqrt{n^2 - 2353}$$ $$n = \sqrt{m^2 + 2353}$$

It looks completely hopeless now, but I'll give a try anyway, to add both.

$$m + n = \sqrt{n^2 - 2353} + \sqrt{m^2 + 2353}$$

And this is where I'm stuck, what steps should I've or next up would've taken? What steps had I done wrong, if  I've done any? Those two questions are the most important. I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Just write $x^2+m^2=y^2+n^2$ as $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)=n^2-m^2$. Here we have $x-y=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $2353+m^2=n^2$

From this step, you can subtract $m^2$ from both sides and factor out the LHS.

$2353 = n^2-m^2 = (n-m)(n+m)$

$2353 = 13\cdot 181$

$13$ and $181$ are both prime, so there are these two cases:

$m-n = 1$, $m+n = 2353$

$m-n = 13$, $m+n = 181$

Solutions of these cases:

---

When you solve the first one, you get $2m = 2354$, $m=1177$, $n=1176$

When you solve the second one, you get $2m = 194$, $m=97$, $n=84$

These are all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As [Dietrich Burde](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83966/dietrich-burde) statet in the comment, you can use [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to rewirte the espression.
\begin{align}
1177^2 + m^2 &= 1176^2 + n^2\\
1177^2 - 1176^2 &= n^2 - m^2\\
2353 &=(n-m)(n+m).
\end{align}
(You could also do $1177^2-1176^2=(1177-1176)(1177+1176)$ and you would not even need a calculator)

Now we are looking at the divisors of $2353$.
$$T_{2353} = \{1, 13, 181, 2353\}$$
Luckily, there are only 4 divisors and 2, which are not one or the number itself. This leads to the equation system
\begin{align}
n-m &= 13,\\
n+m &= 181.
\end{align}
Solving this system gives us $n=97$ and $m=84$